# TYPO3 authenticating user failing using SaltedPasswordsUtility

Tags: authentication, typo3

I want to authenticate a custom FrontendUser via my REST-API in a Controller. I tried to hash the password with *SaltedPasswordsUtility* using [this guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/saltedpasswords/8.7/DevelopersGuide/Index.html).

I get every request a different hash from the same password. I assume this is because the salt is not consistent.

How can I compare the plain text password to the password hash in the database or is there an entirely other way to achieve the same?

My code so far is:

```
  /**
  * action check
  *
  * @param string $username
  * @param string $password
  * @return string
  */
  public function checkAction(string $username, string $password)
  {
    $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByUsername($username);

    $saltedPassword = '';

    if (\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\SaltedPasswordsUtility::isUsageEnabled('FE')) {
            $objSalt = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance(NULL);
            if (is_object($objSalt)) {
                    $saltedPassword = $objSalt->getHashedPassword($password);
            }
    }

    echo $saltedPassword;
    echo "<br>";

    $saltedPassword = $user->getPassword();
    // keeps status if plain-text password matches given salted user password hash
    $success = FALSE;

    if (\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\SaltedPasswordsUtility::isUsageEnabled('FE')) {
      $objSalt = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance($saltedPassword);
      if (is_object($objSalt)) {
        $success = $objSalt->checkPassword($password, $saltedPassword);
      }
    }
    echo $saltedPassword;
    return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is woking. I messed up setting a faulty password for the test user in the backend.